# How can I use mod_rewrite to remove everything after the ? (question mark) in a URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

How can I use mod_rewrite to remove everything after the ?  (question mark) in a URL?

For instance:

```
http://127.0.0.1/ALL_FILES.php?test=1
```

after mod_rewrite:

```
http://127.0.0.1/ALL_FILES.php
```

For php this means that the $_GET super global will always be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) docs:

> The Pattern will not be matched
>   against the query string. Instead, you
>   must use a RewriteCond with the
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variable

Something along the lines of:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
 RewriteRule ^/index.php /index.php? [L,R]
```

should do what you need. If you don't care about what is displayed to the user, but only what gets passed down to php, you can leave out the R flag.

Comment: I want the rules to work for all files on the system,  not just index.php

Comment: Change the rewrite line to this: 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R]